# How to find the unique address of a Google Hangout group chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have been added to a group chat in Google Hangout and I lost the "xxxx UID address" of the group chat. I am able to chat in group using Chrome / Firefox web hangouts, but I cannot chat using jitsi/kopete/empathy (chat clients) etc.

Is it possible to find the UID of the Google Hangout group chat?